# Creating a sticky and closable message in the bottom of the activity (kotlin/java)

Tags: java, kotlin, dialog, message, toast

Does anyone know how to create a closable message like the one in the image in Kotlin?

The idea is not to use snackbars or toasts or dialogs. This message must be immovable and must appear every certain number of times the app is opened.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmtQq.jpg)

I need to create a sticky and closable message that can be added in the main activity of an android application.

Comment: Use a snackbar.

Comment: The idea is not to use snackbars or toasts or dialogs. This message must be immovable and must appear every certain number of times the app is opened.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.